# maven-metadata.xml keeps getting requested when building

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

```
AGP 4.2.2
gradle-6.7.1
arcticfox 2020.3.1
```

Everytime I build my android project I see this maven-metadata.xml and it just seems to slow the build and it just seems to hang there. Which can take 10 minutes for each build.

Is there a way to avoid this?

`Gradle: Download maven-metadata.xml...`

When I run one the command line I see this:

[image]

This is my gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

kotlin.coroutines=enable
kotlin.code.style=official
kapt.use.worker.api=true
kapt.incremental.apt=true

android.enableD8.desugaring=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I am using some maven repositories as specified here in build.gradle(app):

```
maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
maven { url 'http://......./repo/maven2' }
maven { url "https://....../repositories/snapshots" }
maven { url 'https://....../maven/release' }
maven { url "http://......./bintray.com/maven" }
maven { url "https://....../objectbox/objectbox" }
```

Comment: That is coming from some dependency of yours. It feels like the network connection between you and the relevant Maven-style repository is slow. Other than by experimentation, I am not certain how you will be able to determine which specific repository that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle usually needs to download a `maven-metadata.xml` file, if

1. you use a [dynamic/changing version](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/dynamic_versions.html) for one of your dependencies, and
2. the [time to live (TTL)](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/dynamic_versions.html#sec:controlling-dynamic-version-caching) in the dependency cache is over.

For (1) you should look for versions like `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` or `1.2.+` on your declared dependencies (or at `./gradlew dependencies` for simplicity). If you have any such versions, do you really need them? Using fixed versions like `1.2.3` should be faster.

For (2), have you maybe changed the default TTL threshold or do you maybe always build with `--refresh-dependencies`? If not, then the slowness should at least not occur more often than once a day.

If the above doesn’t help, then maybe try running your build with `--info` or `--info --refresh-dependencies` and carefully watch the log output. That should show which dependency and/or which repository is the culprit (i.e., the one on which the logging is stuck for the longest time). If you find such a culprit, then you could look into things like

- replacing the dependency (or the repository),
- improving the speed of the repository server or the network, or
- pruning old snapshot versions from the problematic `maven-metadata.xml` file (if you control the repository).

If all this still doesn’t turn up actionable items, then maybe it could be worth looking for bigger `maven-metadata.xml` files in your Gradle dependency cache. Maybe the repeated download of such big files is the issue and one of the approaches from the previous list could help. Here’s an idea for how to find the ten biggest `maven-metadata.xml` files (with a Unix shell command):

```
find ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/resources-* \
        -name maven-metadata.xml \
        -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | sort -k1 \
    | tail
```

Comment: Thanks, using --info I was able to identify the repo that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The question is kind of insufficient to tell, because no `build.gradle` had been provided. But I'd assume, that the reason is any `-SNAPSHOT` dependency, which is not being cached. Building against a local copy of that dependency should result in not downloading the `maven-metadata.xml` over and over again; or use `mavenLocal()`. Building against a stable version should also result in caching.

Comment: I am not using any mavenLocal(). I have updated my question with the maven repositories I am using in my build.gradle (app) file. When I sync it takes ~3 to 4 minutes because of the meta data. However , if I switch gradle to offline mode  it takes about 5 seconds.

Comment: @ant2009 I have not said that you would use `mavenLocal()`, but providing the dependency from there would also prevent the download, preferable without the `-SNAPSHOT` tag. If you can't determine which package it is, try to find out which repository it is (which might download an awful lot of historic snapshot metadata).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers give very good context on why this happens. Especially when using `-SNAPSHOT` dependencies, if you have no other way, I have a trick for you that might help a lot.

It is to use offline mode

When running via CLI, do

```
./gradlew someTask --ofline
```

When running via IDE, enable offline mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The cause of slow downloads for `maven-metadata.xml` files is that one of your proxy repositories has a very slow remote.
This problem will be compounded if either of the `"metadata max age"` and `"not found cache ttl"` settings is set too low. Thus it will check the circle too fast and download it everytime from scratch. Turn it up to 12 hours. Default should be 30min (1800sec) what is a too short period of time.

For setting the `max age` you can simple follow along this [site](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.guava/guava/23.5-android/source-code/com/google/common/net/HttpHeaders.java).

Another good [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers) to manage `Http Cache Headers`.

Comment: Are you referring to the `/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml` file.  As the settings.xml is just a sample with all properties commented out. So this is not being used. Is there another file where I can check that `metadata max age`` and `not found cache ttl`?

Comment: I updated my answer at the very end. That's how you implement it in your project. You make a class that checks the max age in custom periods. I hope you get an idea, yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Chriki answer directed me in the right direction to find a simple solution. After you have downloaded all dependencies (in my case, I am using -SNAPSHOT library, which wants to be updated on every run), you can set Gradle in offline mode. This will prevent Gradle to download new metadata, etc.

In Android Studio you have a dedicated button to toggle online mode (see image
[Android studio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6poi.png)).